# Displaying images in Liferay themes using FreeMarker

Tags: liferay, freemarker

Velocity has a variable $images_folder (for example, src="$images_folder/image01.png"). I create FreeMarker Plugin and this variable doesn't work (images don't display). What kind of path should I use in portal_normal.ftl instead of $images_folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeMarker has no `$someVariableName`, but `${someExpression}`. So try `src="${images_folder}/image01.png"`

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code which works for me in ftl theme in Liferay DXP

```
<img alt="${logo_description}" height="${site_logo_height}" 
width="${site_logo_width}" src="${images_folder}/logo.png" />
```

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer.  Probably you should just upvote the answer which you'll be able to do once you have enough rep: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges